# Header is sent but response says header is missing

Tags: jquery, ajax, cloudflare

I am trying to send a GET request to Cloudflare's API. I need to send some headers as well, which are `X-Auth-Email` and `X-Auth-Key`. When I add these, either using `headers` as an object or inside `beforeSend: function(xhr)`, Cloudflare still gives me an error, saying I am missing the headers.

This is how the cURL request could look like (and it works):

```
curl -s -X GET "https://api.CloudFlare.com/client/v4/zones?name=DOMAIN.COM&status=active&page=1&per_page=20&order=status&direction=desc&match=all" \
-H "X-Auth-Email: EMAIL@EMAIL.COM" \
-H "X-Auth-Key: 1234567890" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

This is how my `$.ajax()` looks like (and yes, it does default to GET):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.CloudFlare.com/client/v4/zones?name=DOMAIN.COM&status=active&page=1&per_page=20&order=status&direction=desc&match=all",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    headers: {
        "X-Auth-Email": "EMAIL@EMAIL.COM",
        "X-Auth-Key": "1234567890",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Auth-Email", "EMAIL@EMAIL.COM");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Auth-Key", "1234567890");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    }
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

When I then send the request, this is the output I get:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "errors": [{
        "code": 9106,
        "message": "Missing X-Auth-Email header"
    }, {
        "code": 9107,
        "message": "Missing X-Auth-Key header"
    }],
    "messages": [],
    "result": null
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try inspecting the request and see what actually gets sent. jQuery will most likely lowercase the headers, but that shouldn't matter, they should be case-insensitive, unless cloudfare messed up. The use of uppercase letters in the URL does seem strange though, why isn't the domain name lowercase *(not that it matters, but still?)*.

Comment: @adeneo The reason why the variables are uppercase is simply to show you guys which are being sent. In the application it's all lowercase.

Comment: Remove `dataType: "jsonp"`, it ignores the headers and inserts a script tag, not what you want to use for that request.

Comment: @adeneo Didn't work. It's still not sending the headers. I see this when I inspect the request: `access-control-request-headers:content-type,x-auth-email,x-auth-key` - So it does lowercase them. Shouldn't matter though?

Comment: Also, when I remove `jsonp` as the data type, I get an `No Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error. Maybe we're just not supposed to do this using JavaScript.

Comment: Then you're sorta doomed. There's no CORS headers present for that API, and if the API even serves up JSONP, which isn't really ajax at all, but a script tag inserted with a function that returns JSON, you can't add the custom headers.

Comment: You'll need to either drop the headers, or have cloudflare include CORS headers, otherwise you can't do this clientside.

Comment: @adeneo Well that sucks :( Guess I have to do this with PHP then.

Comment: Yes, using your own server as a proxy works fine, and is a common way of solving issues like this. Just make an ajax request to PHP, and let PHP get the data from cloudflare.

Comment: @adeneo Yeah that's usually what I do. I hate when something like this happens :( Thanks for the help, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are setting your headers twice. You should use "headers" OR "beforeSend" to set your headers, not both at the same time.

Comment: That is definitely not the issue.